# Testing a JMS MessageListener

Tags: java, testing, jms, spock, activemq-artemis

I'm not sure how to test a message listener. One thing is the error I receive. The other is I don't even know if I'm on the right track.

```java
class TestListenerTest extends Specification {
    def "TestListener should receive a message"() {
        given:
        Message message = Mock ( Message )
        TestListener listener = new TestListener()

        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory()
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate( connectionFactory )

        when:
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend( "TEST_QUEUE_IN", message )

        then:
        1 * listener.onMessage( message )
    }
}
```

I get the following error (without line break):

```
AMQ229031: Unable to validate user from /127.0.0.1:53051.
Username: null; SSL certificate subject DN: unavailable;
```

When I add a `JMSContext` with `connectionFactory.createContext( "userName", "password")`, the error is still there, just with `userName` instead of `null`. However, I'm not even sure if the way I test it is correct (barring the error).

Comment: How are you configuring & starting the message broker? Is it embedded as part of the test-suite or is it standalone?

Comment: @JustinBertram It's standalone.

Comment: How is the broker configured? I assume you're enforcing security. What does your `etc/login.config` look like?

Comment: @JustinBertram It's a Java class with different beans and default settings like port, username etc. are loaded from another class. I've instantiated the ActiveMQConnectionFactory with a brokerURL from that class, added a context with username and password from that class as well. Now I receive ```javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException: Failed to create session factory```, ```Caused by: ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]```.

Comment: So before you were able to connect but not authenticate and now you're not even able to connect? If so, what changed? Also, how are you configuring security for your broker?

Comment: How about some feedback to my answer? I think it is rather impolite to ask for help in public and then keep your helpers waiting.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say anything about your ActiveMQ problem, because I never worked with that product before, and you did not provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (e.g. on GitHub) to reproduce it.

What I can say is that your Spock test can never work like this:

```java
given:
TestListener listener = new TestListener()

// (...)

then:
1 * listener.onMessage( message )
```

You can only verify interactions on mocks or spies, but you instantiate `listener` like a normal object. So if you wish to check that the listener is actually being called, you need to mock it or spy on an instance. Furthermore, to me it does not look as if the listener has been wired into the system. So how does it know what to listen to? Maybe you have hidden the wiring right inside of class `TestListener` (which sounds a bit weird), but I have no way of knowing.